# ASPM default enabled on kernel 3?

Tags: kernel, hardware, acer

I would like to know if "pcie_aspm=force" is already enabled on kernel 3 or if it will be only for kernel 3.3 like the Phoronix website says. I would like to know because i want to enable it on my acer 3820tg to see if the battery lasts a little more. i'm using ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.

(ps: sorry for my bad english but i'm portuguese)

Celso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the 3.1.1 kernel pciasmp is compiled into the kernel

```
grep ASPM /boot/config-3.1.1
CONFIG_PCIEASPM=y
# CONFIG_PCIEASPM_DEBUG is not set
```

`pcie_aspm=force` looks like a (kernel) boot option.

To enable that option, edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

Add that option in to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, after quiet and splash

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

Update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks ;) I know it's compiled into the kernel but what i want to know too is if that option is already enabled by default. I accept that answer too cause it has useful commands about how to enable it.

Comment: In theory, it should work automatically. If it does not, then you would specify options at boot.

Answer (score 1):

By their nature, a force option must be explicitly configured because it is enabling something that is dangerous, so no, it is not, and will not be set automatically.

Comment: Thanks :D that completes what was missing on bodhi.zazen answer.